# Display a collapsable folder/file tree structure based on array/json object in React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build and display a collapsable tree structure in a react project that is created based on an array object that I get as a response from a backend endpoint call. I want to take the complex json object/ array of files and display then as they appear in the complex json object structure. Does anyone know how to approach something like this or a tool that i can use to accomplish this.

I want to take an object like this:

```
data = [
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "animals",
    path: "/animals",
    children: [
      {
        type: "folder",
        name: "cat",
        path: "/animals/cat",
        children: [
          {
            type: "folder",
            name: "images",
            path: "/animals/cat/images",
            children: [
              {
                type: "file",
                name: "cat001.jpg",
                path: "/animals/cat/images/cat001.jpg"
              }, {
                type: "file",
                name: "cat001.jpg",
                path: "/animals/cat/images/cat002.jpg"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and display it in a react component so that the user sees something like this when he clicks on a dialog box in order to see and click on a file withihn any folder:

```
root
|_ fruits
|___ apple
|______images
|________ apple001.jpg
|________ apple002.jpg
|_ animals
|___ cat
|______images
|________ cat001.jpg
|________ cat002.jpg
```

I have no idea on how to approach getting from the json object to rendering the files structure with clickable files in react component.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-react#treeview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact solution to your problem
[Folder/File Tree Structure Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/explorer-l44v98?file=/index.js)

- We need to build recursive component which will render the items having children as key Recursively in Depth first fashion.

```
const Explorer = ({
  parent = [],
  onParentClick,
  onNameClick,
  expandOnHover = false
}) => {
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState([]);
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewData(parent);
  }, [parent]);

  const handleClickOnParent = (e, data) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // console.log("parent");
    if (onParentClick && onParentClick instanceof Function) {
      onParentClick(data);
    }
    setExpand((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const handleClickOnName = (e, data) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // console.log("child");

    if (onNameClick && onNameClick instanceof Function) {
      onNameClick(data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {newData.map((item, index) => (
        <Fragment key={index}>
          {item.children && item.children.length ? (
            <Fragment key={index}>
              <SelectParent
                onMouseOver={() => (expandOnHover ? setExpand(true) : {})}
                onClick={(e) => handleClickOnParent(e, item)}
              >
                {item.name}{" "}
                <span>
                  {!expand ? <IoMdArrowDropright /> : <MdArrowDropDown />}{" "}
                </span>
              </SelectParent>

              {expand ? (
                <div
                  style={{
                    paddingLeft: "1.5rem"
                  }}
                >
                  <Explorer
                    parent={item.children}
                    onParentClick={onParentClick}
                    onNameClick={onNameClick}
                    expandOnHover={expandOnHover}
                  />
                </div>
              ) : null}
            </Fragment>
          ) : (
            <Selectname onClick={(e) => handleClickOnName(e, item)}>
              {item.name}
            </Selectname>
          )}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```